# Where to show the MIT license for a webpage theme?

Tags: mit, website

I have found 1-2 interesting Jekyll webpage themes that have the MIT license (on http://jekyllthemes.org/).

I want to use an adjusted version of these themes for my webpage and I understand that I have to show their entire license text somewhere.

However, I am not sure where I have to do this. Can I simply copy+paste the MIT license text into the HTML-header (source code)? Create an additional site? Or do I have to also show something like '(c) John Doe under MIT License' at the bottom of the webpage?

Answer (score 3):

As written [here](https://www.tawesoft.co.uk/kb/article/mit-license-faq), the theme license should be put together with other licenses existing in your website, or inside the EULA.

If you don't have such documents, just write the license somewhere into the page footer, or embedded as a HTML comment as you proposed.

The only important thing is that the license is clear and easily readable.